# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", using mocha and enzyme to test ReactJS

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I am using Mocha, Enzyme, Shallow rendering and expect to test ReactJS. **I am not using babel and ES6. I have looked at other questions here on Stack Overflow but none have answered my question.**

I am using ES5 with commonJS and Grunt to compile the JSX to JS and loading the app.built.js file into the html file and it all loads on the page fine.

This is my code in `speedoApp.jsx`

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

module.exports.default = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(<p>Hello</p>);
  }
});
```

This is the code in `App.js`

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var SpeedoApp = require('./speedoApp.jsx').default;

ReactDOM.render(
  <SpeedoApp />,
  document.getElementById('container')
)
```

My HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Speedometer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="./scripts/app.built.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My test file `speedoSpec.js`:

```
var React = require('react');
var expect = require('expect');
var enzyme = require('enzyme');
var shallow = enzyme.shallow;
var SpeedoApp = require('../../react_components/speedoApp.jsx');

describe('Component: speedoApp', function() {
  it('should display \'hello\' on the page', function() {
    var wrapper = shallow(<SpeedoApp />);
    expect(wrapper).to.have.length(1);
  });
});
```

I am getting the error message when I run mocha:

```
var wrapper = shallow(<SpeedoApp />);
                      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I have also tried requiring the `app.built.js` file in replacement to the `speedoApp.jsx` file in `speedoSpec.js`.

Anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: `var wrapper = shallow(<SpeedoApp />);` is JSX not JS. You have it in a JS file.

Comment: I tried renaming it to JSX and still get the same error.

Comment: Script elements for JSX files need explicit type attributes I believe.

Comment: @yasgreen It is not particularly useful to edit your question to explain what you are *not* doing. You should edit it to explain what it is exactly you *are* doing. The code given in [example](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/mocha.html) in the official documentation for Enzyme uses Babel and starts Mocha in a very specific way. The bottom line is that Mocha does not know JSX so *something* has to intervene to translate it to plain JS. Babel is one option. Show the setup you have to build and run tests and then we'll probably have a basis from which to talk.